# SAP hana to aws s3 data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hana, s4hana

I have total 5tb of data in sap Hana. I want to export all the data to aws S3 in csv format. I want to use SAP hana export functionality. Is the service free or any additional cost will be charged to transfer the data?

Comment: where your Hana is hosted? is it on-prem or cloud?