# How to transfer data from SAP HANA to AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hana

I have total 2tb of data in SAP HANA. I want to export all the data to aws s3 in csv format. I want to use SAP hana export functionality. Is the service free of cost or any additional cost will be charged to transfer the data to s3?

Comment: transfer into AWS is free... transfer out, not so much.

Comment: Why do you ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71559910/sap-hana-to-aws-s3-data-transfer) from different accounts? Who are you trying to cheat?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any enterprise tools available? Typically you would want some form of ETL tool (Data Services, Informatica, etc.) to move larger data volumes.

You're going to face some issues doing a traditional 'EXPORT' in HANA unless you have access to the OS level to write the files in Binary to the server, and pick them up to load to AWS S3. Exporting large data volumes in HANA, especially to  CSV, is very heavy on the environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).